# how to convert that syntax to python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

hi i have a very quick question

```
for header in cookie_headers:
    pairs = [pair.partition("=") for pair in header.split(';')]
    cookie_name = pairs[0][0] # the key of the first key/value pairs
    cookie_value = pairs[0][2] # the value of the first key/value pairs
    cookie_parameters = {key.strip().lower():value.strip() for key,sep,value in pairs[1:]}
    cookies.append((cookie_name, (cookie_value, cookie_parameters)))
return dict(cookies)
```

i have a little code like that
cookie_parameters doesn't work with python 2.6
i installed 2.7 but the libs it needs in python 2.6 i confused too much
just need to learn how to write this syntax in 2.6

```
    cookie_parameters = {key.strip().lower():value.strip() for key,sep,value in pairs[1:]}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cookie_parameters = dict((key.strip().lower(), value.strip())
                         for key,sep,value in pairs[1:])
```

More generally, any dict comprehension like this:

```
{<keyexpr>: <valueexpr> for <comprehension_target>}
```

… is equivalent to:

```
dict((<keyexpr>, <valueexpr>) for <comprehension_target>)
```

… because the `dict` constructor can take any iterable of (key, value) pairs.

Except, of course, that the dict comprehension will be faster, but won't work before Python 2.7…

Comment: I'm hoping my abbreviated syntax is understandable. The problem is that there's no good name for "everything after the first `for`". There is a good name for "everything from the first `for` on", [`comp_for`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries), but taking out the `for` makes it much less obvious that this is supposed to be a comprehension…

Answer (score 0):

Dict comprehension was introduced since Python 2.7  See:[What’s New in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features)

There are three ways to construct a dict:

```
class dict(**kwarg) e.g. dict(one=2, two=3)

class dict(mapping, **kwarg) e.g. dict({'one': 2, 'two': 3})
class dict(iterable, **kwarg) e.g. dict(zip(('one', 'two'), (2, 3))) Or dict([['two', 3], ['one', 2]])
```

list comprehensions and generaters are iterables, you could combine dict() with them